# C# using ImageSearch from AutoIt

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm trying to use this [DLL](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/) from AutoIt with C# (ImageSearch)

The DLL is to detect a given image on the screen

This is my code:

```
[DllImport("ImageSearchDLL.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr ImageSearch(int x, int y, int right, int bottom, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string imagePath);

public static String[] UseImageSearch(string imgPath)
{
    int right = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right;
    int bottom = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom;

    IntPtr result = ImageSearch(0, 0, right, bottom, imgPath);
    String res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);

    if (res[0] == '0') return null;//not found

    String[] data = res.Split('|');
    //0->found, 1->x, 2->y, 3->image width, 4->image height;        

    // Then, you can parse it to get x and y:
    int x; int y;
    int.TryParse(data[1], out x);
    int.TryParse(data[2], out y);

    return data;
}
```

So, I'm getting **System.BadImageFormatException** when calling the ImageSearch function at this line:

```
IntPtr result = ImageSearch(0, 0, right, bottom, imgPath);
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: the AutoIt `ImageSearch` function has the following parameters: `ImageSearch("patterntosearch",where,x,y,tolerance)`, where `patterntosearch` is a file name (bmp or png), `where` is 0 or 1 (return midpoint or top left corner) and `tolerance`, a value between 0 (exact match) and 255(? not sure) to accept some amout of color-shift. `x` and `y` receive the found position.

Answer (score 1):

I had a `System.BadImageFormatException` because I was using the **32** bit .dll and my project was set to **x64**

When I changed the .dll for the 64 bits one, everything worked.
Here's how I use it (async mode) :

**CustomApi.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public static class CustomApi
    {
        //The .dll must be in the same folder as the app
        //You can also use [DllImport("C:\\full\\path\\to\\dll.dll")]
        [DllImport("_ImageSearch_x64.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr ImageSearch(int x, int y, int right, int bottom, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string imagePath);


        public static ImageSearchResult SearchImage(string imgFullPath, int tolerance = 0)
        {
            //Don't delete the space
            imgFullPath = $"*{tolerance} {imgFullPath}";

            var result = ImageSearch(1, 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, imgFullPath);
            var res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res) || res[0] == '0')
                return null;

            var data = res.Split('|');
            int.TryParse(data[1], out var x);
            int.TryParse(data[2], out var y);

            return new ImageSearchResult(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageSearchResult.cs**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class ImageSearchResult
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public ImageSearchResult(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainForm.cs**

```cs
public static async Task<ImageSearchResult> FindImage(string imageFullPath, int timeOut = 15)
        {
            
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ImageSearchResult result = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < timeOut; i++)
                {
                    result = CustomApi.SearchImage(imageFullPath, tolerance: 0);
                    if (result != null)
                        break;

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                return result;
            });

        }


        //Put this wherever you want
        var result = await FindImage(@"C:\my_image.bmp"); //Must be .bmp
        if (result == null)
            Console.WriteLine("c non");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Found : X:{result.X} Y:{result.Y}");
```

Downloaded the .dlls from [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/files/file/471-image-search-udf/)

Also, uploaded them to [ZippyShare](https://www98.zippyshare.com/v/FyOww2G1/file.html) just in case

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `System.BadImageFormatException` because you're passing a zero for the first argument, it should be the filename of the image.

Usage example:

`ImageSearch('checkImage.bmp', 0, 100, 500, 0)`